# Flutter Flame: proper Viewport to match the screen size

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

How can I find out the screen size and place my game item according to screen resolution? I want to run my game on the web client.

[image: component outside of the screen]

I want to resize my red game component so fit in the screen and position in center.
LibGdx has some good java class for this concept: [Link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/ExtendViewport.html)

Comment: I updated my answer with `FixedResolutionViewport` after I read your LibGDX link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `FixedResolutionViewport` and set it to the smallest  edge if you always want it as a square.

**With the CameraComponent**

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    double maxSide = min(size.x, size.y);
    final cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
      world: myWorldComponent,
      width: maxSide,
      height: maxSide,
    );
    ...
  }
}
```

or

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final cameraComponent = CameraComponent(
      world: myWorldComponent,
      viewport: FixedAspectRatioViewport(aspectRatio: 1.0),
    );
    ...
  }
}
```

**With the old Camera**

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    double maxSide = min(size.x, size.y);
    camera.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(Vector2.all(maxSide)); 
  }
}
```

If you want the game's (viewport) `size` inside of another component you can add the `HasGameRef` mixin and use the game's `size` variable in the same way:

```dart
class MyComponent extends Component with HasGameRef {
    MyComponent() : super(anchor: Anchor.center);

  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final gameSize = gameRef.size;
    // To add a position component in the center of the screen for example:
    // (when the camera isn't moved)
    position = gameSize/2;
  }
}
```

If you want other sizes I recommend to look at `game.camera` and `game.camera.viewport` which offers a few other options too.

Comment: Is there any way that we can set map at center of different device resolutions  ?

Comment: What do you mean by map here?

Comment: What's the equivalent for flame 1.8 ? because it seems that game has no camera property there. thank you

Comment: And CameraComponent viewport seems to be readonly

Comment: @Vahid2023 updated with instructions for the CameraComponent